# MQ channel status - via PCF

Tags: ibm-mq

I am issuing `INQUIRE_CHANNEL_STATUS` command via PCF , I am getting Byte sent, Byte Received.
Now I want to also obtain the the channel status.  Would I get that under MQCFST ?

After the MQGET,  I am not seeing  `MQIACH_CHANNEL_STATUS = PCF_TYPE(String)`.

Has anyone come across of this ?

Answer (score 1):

Bytes sent (`MQIACH_BYTES_SENT`) and bytes received (`MQIACH_BYTES_RCVD`) are both numbers/integers, so they are conveyed to you in the `MQCFIN` structure (MQ Command Format INteger).

The channel status field (`MQIACH_CHANNEL_STATUS`) which tells you whether the channel is running (`MQCHS_RUNNING`) or retrying (`MQCHS_RETRYING`) or so on, is also an integer, so it will not be in an `MQCFST` (MQ Command Format STring) but it will also be in an `MQCFIN` just as the bytes sent and bytes received values are.

You can discover the types and attribute constants for all the fields that come back as part of an `MQCMD_INQUIRE_CHANNEL_STATUS` PCF command response message, by viewing [this page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=dpcf-mqcmd-inquire-channel-status-inquire-channel-status-response) in IBM Docs.

You have not provided any code snippet in your question, nor any hint of what language you are using, so I have not put any code in this answer, but if you update your question to show the code you are using, I will update this answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As Morag mentioned, you should have provided code samples and said what programming language you are using.

I have posted many Java/PCF sample programs on my blog [here](https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?cat=67).  In particular, there is a blog posting called '[Java MQ Code to List Channel Status](https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=6587)' that shows you exactly what you are looking for.